# How can I efficiently bulk update the list of tags for an item in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I basically want to do a complement set operation in SQLite but not sure how.

Say I have a list of tags for an item like this in memory:

```
"red", "blue", "green", "yellow"
```

and the database has these tags associated with the same item:

```
"red", "orange", "purple"
```

What I want is to have the database reflect the state in memory. I need to:

1. Delete the relationship to the tags for the item in the database that do not exist in memory. Delete "organge" and "purple."
2. Add the tag relationships I do not have in database but do in memory. Add "blue", "green", and "yellow".

I could simply grab the entire list of existing tags and do the operation outside of SQL with Java (on Android), but that could be a huge list and I'm doing this on a mobile device.

I could also drop all existing tag relationships for the item and then add the ones in memory but that could potentially add a lot of relationships that already exist and seems like unnecessary work.

I basically have the following tables:

item

```
id, int primary key autoincrement not null
name, text
```

tag

```
id, int primary key autoincrement not null
name text
```

tagged_items

```
id, int primary key autoincrement not null
tag_id, int
item_id, int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say I have a list of tags for an item like this in memory... and the database has these tags associated with the same item

One approach would be to have your in-memory representation hold both the current state and the last-persisted state.

Then, when it comes time to update the database, you know exactly what needs to be INSERTed and DELETEd from `tagged_items` (and, possibly, INSERTed into `tags`), by performing [set difference operations](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Setoperationsunionintersectiondifferencesymmetricdifferenceissubsetissuperset.htm).

This assumes that you either:

- get rid of the extraneous integer primary key for your `tags` table, since a tag should be unique already, or
- you hold in memory both the tag and its ID

You might be able to get away with holding only the tag in memory via sub-SELECTs to derive an `id` from the tag text, but personally I'd just nuke the `id` column from `tags`.

When you do the database I/O, wrap it all in a transaction, not only because logically the work should succeed or fail as a whole, but to boost performance with SQLite on Android.

Another approach would be for you to get rid of your direct SQLite access and switch to something like [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) that might handle this sort of thing for you. I haven't used it personally.

Comment: If I get rid of the tag id, do I need the tag table at all?

Comment: @BjornTipling: Perhaps not. If it performs well enough, a `SELECT DISTINCT` on `tagged_items` could give you the set of in-use tags. If you had the notion of a defined tag that had no tagged items, that would force you to maintain the roster of defined tags elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would sort both lists by "item_id + tag_id" and make shure that the database select only affect those itemIDs that are in the memory list.

```
select item_id, tag_id from tagged_items 
  where item_id in (... list of  memory item_id ...) 
  order by item_id, tag_id
```

and then

- either advance the smaller list-item or
- or advance both list-item if both list-items are equal

Example:

assuming these tag_ids: "red"=1, "blue"=2, "green"=3, "yellow"=4, "orange"=5, "purple"=6.
current item_id of the example data is 97

- mem 97,1-red db 97,1-red

  - both same
  - no db action
  - advance both
- mem 97,2-blue db 97,5-orange

  - mem < db
  - insert 97,2-blue
  - advance mem
- mem 97,3-green db 97,5-orange

  - mem < db
  - insert 97,3-green
  - advance mem
- mem 97,4-yello db 97,5-orange

  - mem < db
  - insert 97,4-yello
  - advance mem
- mem 98,4-yello db 97,5-orange

  - mem > db (next mem item, 97,5-orange is not in DB any more)
  - delete 97,5-orange
  - advance db

Comment: I assume that this solution is nearly equivalent to @CommonsWare version but it replaces "keep the old state in memory" with a "old-state db cursor". This solution should also work for combining two android content-resolvers